# Groupe prépositionnel introduit par "Selon"

Tags: grammaire, fonction-grammaticale

Soit la phrase suivante :

- « **Selon les autorités**, le suspect a des antécédents. »

Hors le fait d'être un Complément de Phrase (CP), qui est une dénomination récente, quelle est la fonction grammaticale traditionnelle du syntagme (groupe) prépositionnel *'Selon les autorités'* ?

**Pour préciser :**

Le qualificatif « récent » est relatif, je vous le concède, la terminologie traditionnelle l'est tout autant, mais cette dernière avait pour avantage d'assigner un lien, une logique ou une acception à chaque complément circonstanciel (temps, lieu, manière, condition, concession, mesure, moyen, cause, conséquence, but, etc.), la vraie question est donc : si on devait assigner un nom ou une précision audit complément circonstanciel, ce serait laquelle ? On dira que c'est un *complément circonstanciel de [...]* ?

Comment: La notion de «  récent » est relative, elle est interprétée différemment selon les individus (leur âge, leur éducation, leur culture etc.), cette fausse précision n'apporte rien à la question. Un individu scolarisé en primaire a entendu cette dénomination qui a remplacé celle de complément circonstanciel il y a une quarantaine d'années (elle était employée par les linguistes avant ça). Quarante ans peut être récent pour certains, pas pour d'autres.

Comment: Ou alors ta question est mal formulée : veux-savoir quel autre nom porte (ou *portait en grammaire « traditionnelle »*)  le [complément de phrase](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/guide/qu-est-ce-qu-un-complement-circonstanciel-ou-complement-de-phrase) ?

Comment: @None J'ai ajouté une précision !

Answer (score 1):

Si je voulais rester dans le cadre scolaire restreint je dirais que *selon*  introduit ici un [complément circonstanciel de cause](https://www.cordial.fr/grammaire/manuels/CAUSALE.htm). On pourrait en effet reformuler la phrase ainsi :

- Parce que les autorités l'ont dit, le suspect a des antécédents.

Mais cette réponse ne me satisfait pas vraiment, car *selon* laisse planer sur les faits un soupçon d'incertitude que gomme *parce que*.

De façon à respecter cette incertitude je trouve qu'il serait plus exact de reformuler ainsi :

- Étant donné/compte tenu de ce qu'ont dit les autorités, le suspect a des antécédents.

Mon édition du *Bon usage** recense vingt-neuf  circonstances « principales », en précisant que ces circonstances sont « extrêmement variées ». Pour le cas envisagé dans la question, parmi les circonstances citées par les auteurs du *Bon usage*, je suis tentée de privilégier la circonstance du « point de vue ». Et rien ne m'empêche de créer une circonstance voisine de celle-ci : la circonstance du ouï-dire.

---

*<sub>10 <sup>e</sup> édition ; « Complément circonstanciel », § 200.</sub>

Comment: L'opinion reste subjective, et je suis d'accord avec vous à propos de l'insatisfaction, déjà que la structure complexe ne fait que rendre l'analyse plus difficile qu'elle ne l'est déjà, et peut-être même la fausser, et pour preuve, en faisant fi de l'absence de rapport de cause à effet, le passage de la conjonctive circonstancielle à un groupe prépositionnel exprimant le même rapport de cause, permet de se rendre compte de l'infaisabilité de cette approche, on peut appuyer cette critique en rappelant que la cause répond généralement à la question : *pourquoi ?*